# Examples of functions with natural boundary that do not satisfy Fabry or Hadamard gap theorem condition

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, examples, power-series

there are examples of lacunary functions with natural boundary that do not satisfy Fabry or Hadamard gap theorem condition.I want to know more examples of those functions,the more the better,especially the ones in closed form or series with integer coefficients.

And is there any research or theorem by which we can know or decide such a series that does not satisfy  Fabry or Hadamard gap theorem condition has natural boundary?

**EDIT:** adding and multiplying a a function with domain containing the closed unit disk  has to be regards as an equivalent example,that is example is the same one up to adding and multiplying a a function with domain containing the closed unit disk

Comment: One example is $$G(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$$
It may be written as $$G(z)=z + 2z^2 + 2z^3 + 3z^4 + 2z^5 + 4z^6 + \dots  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tau (n)x^n$$$\tau (n)$is the number of divisors of  $n$ ,The function has unit circle as a natural boundary, but does not satisfy Fabry or Hadamard gap theorem condition.

Comment: Another is not in the class of what Fabry or Hadamard gap theorem concerns,but it is very similar to the example above. here,I quote from a master thesis:Poincare  simple poles,Let $L$ be a smooth closed curve which bounds a convex set in the plane, $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence of dense distinct points on $L$, and $\{c_n\}$ be an absolutely
summable sequence of non-zero complex numbers. define $f$ to be the function$$f(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{z-z_n} \text{,where }z\notin L$$Then $f(z)$ ($f(z)$ restricted to the interior of $L$) does not have an analytic continuation across any point of $L$

Comment: This is extremely broad. Adding a function with domain containing the closed unit disk to a lacunary function doesn't change its natural boundary. To mention a huge family of very restricted, atypical lacunary functions, nonconstant functions on cusped finite volume Riemann surfaces lift to lacunary functions on the universal cover, and these generally don't satisfy the Fabry or Hadamard gap conditions.

Comment: @DouglasZare,thanks,why don't you make your comment as an answer,and I have to edit my post in some words to say that adding and multiplying a a function with domain containing the closed unit disk has to be regards as an equivalent example,that is example is the same one up to adding and multiplying a a function with domain containing the closed unit disk

Comment: Another class of function  that don't satisfy the Fabry or Hadamard gap conditions: Theorem (Szeg$\ddot{o}$, 1922). If $$f (z) = \sum a_nz_n$$ and the set of
values of ${a_n}$ is a finite set, then either $|z| = 1$ is a natural
boundary, or else an is eventually periodic, in which case $f$is a rational function with poles on $\mathbb{\partial D}$.